# MySQL: Can't CREATE TRIGGER, ERROR IN DECLARE

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a trigger but the error shown after typed DECLARE.

> mysql> delimeter //

```
-> CREATE TRIGGER a_b
-> BEFORE UPDATE ON a
-> FOR EACH ROW
-> BEGIN
->      DECLARE   cur_date   DATE;
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimeter //
CREATE TRIGGER a_b
BEFORE UPDATE ON a
FOR EACH ROW
B' at line 1
mysql>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct word is DELIMITER. Besides that, use TOAD for MySQL or AquaData Studio for comfortable database development